# Javascript > HTML spitting out plain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ubuntu

i have a small problem but i cant find the problem myself :/

So i have this small part of code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Chat</title>
<style>
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
body { font:13px Helvetica, Arial; }
form { background: #000; padding:3px; position:fixed; bottom:0; width:100%;}
form input { border:0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%;}
form button { width:9%; background: rgb(130,224,255); border: none; padding:10px;}
#messages { list-style-type: none; margin:0; padding:0;}
#messages li { padding: 5px 10px;}
#messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<ul id="messages"></ul>
<form action="">
<input id="m" autocomplete="off"/><button>Send</button>
</form>

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script
<script>
var socket = io();
$('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
});
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But, the part between the `<script></script>` where the var socket = io();
starts is being spit out as plain text...

[image]

And i cant find the problem, maybe one of you guys know...

Thanks!

Comment: Rather than including a screenshot, could you edit your question to include the actual code?

Comment: Oh sorry haha i edited it

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console window?  Have you looked at the code [HERE](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/public/main.js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a `>`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script
```

Should be:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that shall do the trick haha thanks!

Comment: @LucStey James laid it on pretty thick but it's highly appreciated if you accept the answer you found most helpful. It's a great way to say "thank you" ;)

Comment: btw. typo questions shouldn't be answered, but closed with a comment showing the typo... Enjoy free rep ;)

Comment: @Shomz I took your advice to heart haha

Comment: Hey, I think it was you when you wrote a comment which was an answer, and I asked you to write it as an answer, but you said you didn't want to earn rep like that, but then someone else took your comment, wrote an answer, and earned free rep :D  Karma! :)

Comment: I felt so dumb, ive probably watched a dozen times over that mistake already..

Answer (score 1):

This line right here:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script
```

Is missing the closing `>` after `</script`

```js
var socket = io();
$('form').submit(function() {
  socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
  $('#m').val('');
  return false;
});
socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
  $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
});
```

```css
* {

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

  box-sizing: border-box;

}

body {

  font: 13px Helvetica, Arial;

}

form {

  background: #000;

  padding: 3px;

  position: fixed;

  bottom: 0;

  width: 100%;

}

form input {

  border: 0;

  padding: 10px;

  width: 90%;

  margin-right: .5%;

}

form button {

  width: 9%;

  background: rgb(130, 224, 255);

  border: none;

  padding: 10px;

}

#messages {

  list-style-type: none;

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

}

#messages li {

  padding: 5px 10px;

}

#messages li:nth-child(odd) {

  background: #eee;

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Chat</title>

</head>

<body>

  <ul id="messages"></ul>
  <form action="">
    <input id="m" autocomplete="off" />
    <button>Send</button>
  </form>

  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The closing `script` tag is missing a `>`.

Try:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```